# Support multiple application servers through Maven

Tags: java, maven, websphere, wildfly

We have a Java web application that is deployed on Wildfly. However, one client now wants to use WebSphere. We've found that the included `jar` files in the `lib` folder of our `war` file need to be a little different between Wildfly and WebSphere - WebSphere doesn't like having some of the libs that Wildfly is fine with (different libraries provided by the AS?).

We would like to automate this as much as possible, although I assume there's probably going to be *some* manual fiddling in a `pom.xml` or `build.xml` file when it comes time to build for one or the other. But is there a good, sane way to filter the `jar` files appropriately? The only thing I can think of is using `<exclusions>` in the `pom.xml` file, but I don't see how to sensibly control that if I want to build for one AS vs the other, other than just commenting a bunch of `<exclusions>` or `<scope>`s out, which seems impractical.

Is it possible to do this through Maven somehow, in a nearly totally automated fashion? Or what's the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [build profiles.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

They allow you to activate/deactivate parts of the POM. So you define a profile `websphere` and a profile `wildfly`. You put the vendor specific dependencies into the profiles (you can also put the same dependency in each of the profiles with different exclusions).

You can then activate/deactivate the profiles either from the command line, from the `settings.xml` or through the presence of absence of a given file.

Comment: I'll give this a try and see how it goes, but it sounds like exactly what we're looking for.